# Is it possible to animate a modifier in 3ds Max?

Tags: animation, 3ds-max

Is it possible to 'animate in' a modifier?

Elaboration:

I want a cube to behave as a regular cube for, say, 10 frames, and only after 10 frames should a cloth modifier fade into the cube.

This means for 10 frames the cube will behave as if there are no modifiers on it, then after 10 frames the cloth modifier will fade in on the cube and simulate normally as a cloth object would thereafter.

Any help will be appreciated, and any links would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set to Auto-keyframe, head to frame 0, and reduce all the properties of the modifier to 0 (or whatever creates NO impact on the underlying object). Now you have your begin state.

From there, add whatever you need at later frames to animate in the total impact of the modifier.

Some Modifiers, by virtue of the way they work, may not be able to have a zero state (zero impact) upon the rest of their stack. But most should.

You can then head to the animation timeline to set the keyframes to eases of your choice to gracefully build the impact of the effects of the modifiers on your stack.

In this manner you can do some amazing things with modifies.  Particularly if you use wave modifiers to modify their values.